# Parameters issue with Insert Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio

I get this error message from my `Try catch`:

> The parameterized query '(@UserID int, @date date, @BreakfastLevels float, @LunchLevels floa' expects the parameter '@UserID', which was not supplied

The code is designed to take values put into a data grid view from a form and insert them to the table in the database however I get the error message above. I'm still quite new to coding and really need the help here.

This is my code:

```
 Private Sub UpdateButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles UpdateButton.Click
        Dim con As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.DiabetesServerConStr)

        Dim insertNewValues As New SqlCommand()
        insertNewValues.Connection = con

        insertNewValues.Parameters.Add("@UserID", SqlDbType.Int)
        insertNewValues.Parameters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.Date).Value = Date.Today()
        insertNewValues.Parameters.Add("@BreakfastLevels", SqlDbType.Float)
        insertNewValues.Parameters.Add("@LunchLevels", SqlDbType.Float)
        insertNewValues.Parameters.Add("@DinnerLevels", SqlDbType.Float)
        insertNewValues.Parameters.Add("@BedLevels", SqlDbType.Float)
        insertNewValues.Parameters.Add("@BreakfastCarbs", SqlDbType.Float)
        insertNewValues.Parameters.Add("@LunchCarbs", SqlDbType.Float)
        insertNewValues.Parameters.Add("@DinnerCarbs", SqlDbType.Float)
        insertNewValues.Parameters.Add("@BreakfastInsulin", SqlDbType.Float)
        insertNewValues.Parameters.Add("@LunchInsulin", SqlDbType.Float)
        insertNewValues.Parameters.Add("@DinnerInsulin", SqlDbType.float)

        Dim parcomstr As String = "INSERT INTO BloodSugarDiary (UserID, Date, BreakfastLevels, LunchLevels, DinnerLevels, BedLevels, BreakfastCarbs, LunchCarbs, DinnerCarbs, BreakfastInsulin, LunchInsulin, DinnerInsulin)VALUES (@UserID, @Date, @BreakfastLevels, @LunchLevels, @DinnerLevels, @BedLevels, @BreakfastCarbs, @LunchCarbs, @DinnerCarbs, @BreakfastInsulin, @LunchInsulin, @DinnerInsulin)"
        insertNewValues.CommandText = parcomstr

        Try
            con.Open()
            insertNewValues.ExecuteNonQuery()
            con.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
        con.Dispose()
    End Sub
```

Comment: You declared `@UserID` as a param, but you never supplied a value to it.  (You only supplied the `@Date` param's value)

Comment: So what should I add? Sorry I'm still new to coding.

Answer (score 0):

Specify a value for the `@UserID` parameter as [Siyual](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3393505/siyual) suggests, in the same way you already have for the `@Date` parameter:

```
insertNewValues.Parameters.Add("@UserID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 1
```

Replace the `1` with whatever static value you want, or a variable containing the relevant value you wish to insert into `BloodSugarDiary.UserID`. You probably want to specify values for the other parameters in the same way, unless you do not want to insert values for those columns.